# Can I have a list of templates to instantiate, without instantiating prior?

Tags: c++, templates

Not sure how best to phrase this question. I am limited on memory, stack space, have no heap, and no `std`; this results in needing everything to exist on the stack.

I have a few objects that can be pretty large (extrapolate from my small example here, please; a response of "Just make static instances of every type during initialization" is to miss the point of my question).

A code example might work best:

```
template <typename T1, typenameT2>
class Foo {
    public:
    void doStuff(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0: {
            T0 t;
            t.run();
            break;
        }

        case 1: {
           T1 t;
           t.run();
           break;
        }
        // etc; there are more than a couple.
}
```

Ultimately, what I'd prefer is to do something like:

```
void doStuff(int index) {
    // sanity check index first;
    myTemplates[index] t;
    t.run();
}
```

As I've set it up, I obviously don't have a `mytemplates` array; that's my question is - can I do something like that, rather than having such a large, repetitive `switch`-statement?

I realize I can't make an actual array of instantiated types, because the types are different, that's the whole point. Even if I could, I don't want an array of *instantiations*, I want an "array" of template-types.

If it's relevant, all my types, `T0`, `T1`, etc. derive from the same base.

Comment: would that help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477.aspx
pair that with variadic macros or similar.

Comment: @Alex - oh, interesting, let me look into that for a little and get back to you.

Comment: a bit of chrome stealing on how to safe typing on the "array" part: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2012/01/24/higher-order-macros-in-c/

Comment: Haven't you had a look at [boost mpl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html)? May be you could try to mimic it? But I think it is quite heavy for your task though

Comment: All good stuff so far; it'll take me a little to crunch through it, and see if I can use them on this project, but thanks! And higher order macros is fascinating; I can certainly have some fun with that :)

Comment: Is `index` value known at compile time?

Comment: @Jarod42 nope - I actually want index to be the result of a call to some `random` function.

Comment: @Jarod42 were you asking in relevance to preprocessor `##` token pasting? I finally got to a good testing point, and it isn't working, probably because I want to use the contents of some variable, which obviously isn't available at compile time for `##` processing, right?

Comment: preprocessor is even done before, and doesn't know the content of variable. My question was mostly do know if a call like `doStuff<Index>()` is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like:

```
template <typename Ts...>
struct doStuffHelper
{
    template <typename T>
    static void doStuffT()
    {
        T t;
        t.run();
    }

    void operator () (std::size_t i) const
    {
         std::array<void(*)(), sizeof...(Ts)> fs {&doStuffT<Ts>...};

         fs[i]();
    }

};

void doStuff(int index) {
    doStuffHelper<T0, T1 /*, ..*/>{}(index);
}
```